# Javascript: How do I prevent reappending a string to multiple queries?

Tags: javascript, append

In this case, lets take YouTube as an example:

The below code, I believe, is scripted to append a string to `search_query=`, but it gets appended to  `&page=` as well.

[image]

```
if (oSession.uriContains("www.youtube.com/results?search_query=")) 
{
  var str = oSession.fullUrl;
  var sAppend = "+test1+test2+test3";
  if (oSession.fullUrl.indexOf(sAppend, str.length - sAppend.length) < 0)
  {
     oSession.fullUrl = str + sAppend;
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this really Javascript? The code in your image looks like Java. Javascript doesn't have `public static function` syntax.

Comment: The code is JScript .NET, which is basically a .NET version of Javascript.Regardless of language, Anyone with `appending` type of skill can answers my question.

Comment: I don't see any way that that could be inserting the `+test1+test2+test3` in the middle of the URL. It should only append it. Something else must be doing the second append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
if (oSession.uriContains("www.youtube.com/results?search_query=")) 
{
  var str = oSession.fullUrl;
  var sAppend = "+test1+test2+test3";
  if (!oSession.uriContains(sAppend))
  {
     oSession.fullUrl = str + sAppend;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify in question, what you want to achieve.

Comment: My Goal:Append `+test1+test2+test3` to query,then before data reaches the web browser **hide** the `+test1+test2+test3` present in the search box. Example http://i.imgur.com/sfBeiRR.png

Comment: As you can see, using **oSession.utilReplaceInResponse**, I tried to replace `+test1+test2+test3` with `blank`, but Failed. Is there any alternative method? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault, semicolon was missing.Thank you very much for helping me.